# If the roots of $z^4+az^3+bz^2+z$ are distinct and concyclic in the complex plane, does $ab\in\mathbb R$ imply $1<ab<9$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials, contest-math, plane-geometry

HMMT February 2022, Team Round, Problem 6 (proposed by *Akash Das*) is:

> Let $\operatorname{\it P\!}{\left(x\right)}=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+x$ be a polynomial with four distinct roots that lie on a circle in the complex plane. Prove that $ab\neq9$.

Its solution may be found [here](https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2022/feb/team/solutions.pdf#page=3).
Recently, certain netizens **claim**ed that there exists a stronger result when $ab$ is real:

> Let $P(z)=z^4+az^3+bz^2+z$ be a polynomial with four distinct roots that are concyclic in the complex plane; then $ab\in\mathbb R\implies1<ab<9$.

Nevertheless, I could find neither any proof nor any counterexample of it.
Does the above proposition hold?  (And what if $ab\in{\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R}$?)

Edit. It appears that when $ab\in{\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R}$, $ab$ can take any values in the complex plane other than the real axis. Here is a simulation: [image: Powered by the Wolfram Language]

Comment: You could perhaps start with the equivalent assumption that the three roots of $z^3 + b z^2 + a z + 1$ are distinct and collinear.

Comment: @Sahaj It is not the same polynomial. The roots of this one are the inverses of the roots of the first polynomial. The circle contains $(0,0)$, hence its inverse is a straight line.

Comment: I didn't read your comment properly. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, the problem is equivalent to showing
that if $ a b \in  \mathbb{R}$ and the polynomial

\begin{equation}P \left(z\right) = {z}^{3}+b {z}^{2}+a z+1\end{equation}

has three colinear distinct roots on a line that does not
contain zero, then $1  <  a b  <  9$. We prove here that
this result is true in the general case, when $ a$
and $ b$ are complex numbers. Let us define

\begin{equation}a b = {m}^{3} , \qquad  b = m c , \quad  a = \frac{{m}^{2}}{c} , \quad  m \in  {\mathbb{R}}^{\ast } , \quad  c \in  {\mathbb{C}}^{\ast }\end{equation}

hence

\begin{equation}P \left(z\right) = {z}^{3}+m c {z}^{2}+\frac{{m}^{2}}{c} z+1\end{equation}

Let $ \frac{c}{w} \in  {\mathbb{C}}^{\ast }$ a direction vector of
the line $ L$ containing the roots. This line
contains the average of the three roots, which is
$-\frac{m c}{3}$, hence if $ z$ is a root,

\begin{equation}z = m c \left(\frac{t}{w}-\frac{1}{3}\right) , \qquad  t \in  \mathbb{R}\end{equation}

Substituting into $ P$ gives

\begin{equation}P \left(z\right) = {t}^{3} \frac{{m}^{3} {c}^{3}}{{w}^{3}}+t \left(1-\frac{{c}^{3}}{3}\right) \frac{{m}^{3}}{w}+\frac{2 {m}^{3} {c}^{3}}{27}-\frac{{m}^{3}}{3}+1\end{equation}

By multiplying by  $ \frac{{w}^{3}}{{m}^{3} {c}^{3}}$, one finds a
new depressed cubic polynomial
which must now have three real roots

\begin{equation}Q \left(t\right) = {t}^{3}+p t+q = {t}^{3}+t \left(\frac{1}{{c}^{3}}-\frac{1}{3}\right) {w}^{2}+{w}^{3} \left(\frac{2}{27}+\frac{1}{{c}^{3}} \left(\frac{1}{a b}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)\end{equation}

Obviously the conditions are now $ \left(p , q\right) \in  {\mathbb{R}}^{2}$ and $ 27 {q}^{2}+4 {p}^{3}  <  0$.
In particular, it is necessary that $ p  <  0$.
As $ w$
is determined up to an arbitrary non-zero factor, it can be
scaled so that
$ p =-1$. It follows that

\begin{equation}{c}^{3} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{{w}^{2}}}\end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}q = \left(\frac{2}{27 \left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{{w}^{2}}\right)}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{a b}\right) \left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{{w}^{2}}\right) {w}^{3} \in  \mathbb{R}\end{equation}

Let us now define the complex numbers

\begin{equation}{\mu} = {\xi}+i {\zeta} = \frac{2}{27 \left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{{w}^{2}}\right)}-\frac{1}{3} , \qquad  {\nu} = {{\xi}'}+i {{\zeta}'} = \left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{{w}^{2}}\right)^{-1}{w}^{-3}\end{equation}

One has

\begin{equation}{\xi}+\frac{1}{a b}+i {\zeta} = q {{\xi}'}+i q {{\zeta}'} \qquad  \text{hence} \qquad  q = \frac{{\zeta}}{{{\zeta}'}} \quad  \text{and} \quad  \boxed{\frac{1}{a b} = {{\xi}'} \frac{{\zeta}}{{{\zeta}'}}-{\xi}}\end{equation}

The cubic equation has three real roots if and only if
$ 27 {q}^{2}  <  4$ that is to say

\begin{equation}\boxed{27 {{\zeta}}^{2}  <  4 {{{\zeta}'}}^{2}}\end{equation}

We now use Sympy to perform symbolic calculations. Let

\begin{equation}w = x+i y\end{equation}

According to Sympy, the above three real roots condition reduces to

\begin{equation}27 {{\zeta}}^{2}  -  4 {{{\zeta}'}}^{2} = \frac{12 y^2 (4 {x}^{2}-3)}{|w|^4 |w^2 -3|^2}  <  0\end{equation}

which means that $\Im(w)\not = 0$ and $ \Re{\left(w\right)} \in  \left]{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} , \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right[$. The
computation gives

\begin{equation}a b = 9 \frac{3+{y}^{2}-3 {x}^{2}}{9+{y}^{2}-3 {x}^{2}}\end{equation}

As $ {y}^{2}-3 {x}^{2}$ can take any value in
$ \left]{-\frac{9}{4}} , \infty \right[$, it follows that

\begin{equation}1 = 9 \frac{3-\frac{9}{4}}{9-\frac{9}{4}}  <  a b  <  9 \frac{\frac{3}{\infty }+1}{\frac{9}{\infty }+1} = 9\end{equation}

All the values in this interval can be reached.

Let us conclude this with the Python code that performs the symbolic
calculations

```
from sympy import re, im, I, E, symbols, ratsimp, factor, expand_complex

x, y = symbols("x y", real=True)
U = -I * I


def abs2(z):
    return expand_complex(z * z.conjugate()).simplify()


w = x * U + y * I

d = U / 3 - U / w**2

W = abs2(w)
T = abs2(w**2 - 3)
print(f"W = |w|**2 = {W}")
print(f"T = |w**2 - 3|**2 = {T}")

mu = expand_complex(2 / (27 * d) - U / 3).simplify()
nu = expand_complex(1 / (d * w**3)).simplify()
print(f"mu: {mu}")
print(f"nu: {nu}")

xi, zeta = mu.as_real_imag()
xip, zetap = nu.as_real_imag()
print(f"T * xi = {factor((xi*T).simplify())}")
print(f"T * zeta = {factor((zeta*T).simplify())}")
print(f"T * W * xip = {factor((xip*T*W).simplify())}")
print(f"T * W * zetap = {factor((zetap*T*W).simplify())}")

crit = factor(((27 * zeta**2 - 4 * zetap**2) * T * W**2).simplify())
print(f"criterion: {crit} < 0")

ab = 1 / ratsimp(xip * zeta / zetap - xi).simplify()
print(f"ab: {ab}")
```

The output is

```
W = |w|**2 = x**2 + y**2
T = |w**2 - 3|**2 = x**4 + 2*x**2*y**2 - 6*x**2 + y**4 + 6*y**2 + 9
mu: (-x**2 - 2*I*x*y + y**2 + 9)/(9*(x**2 + 2*I*x*y - y**2 - 3))
nu: 3/(x**3 + 3*I*x**2*y - 3*x*y**2 - 3*x - I*y**3 - 3*I*y)
T * xi = -(x**4 + 2*x**2*y**2 - 12*x**2 + y**4 + 12*y**2 + 27)/9
T * zeta = -4*x*y/3
T * W * xip = 3*x*(x**2 - 3*y**2 - 3)
T * W * zetap = -3*y*(3*x**2 - y**2 - 3)
criterion: 12*y**2*(4*x**2 - 3) < 0
ab: 9*(-3*x**2 + y**2 + 3)/(-3*x**2 + y**2 + 9)
```

Comment: Many thanks. In addition, I was also wondering what will happen if $ab\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ (Perhaps, $\Re{{\left(ab\right)}}$ or ${\left\lvert ab\right\rvert}$?) as the original problem does require $ab$ to be real.

Comment: Really my whole study relies on the assumption that $a b$ is real. It is this assumption that gives the equation $\zeta = q \zeta^\prime$. You can perhaps use the same paremetrization of the problem in $w$ to say a little more when $a b$ is not real. Why did you unaccept the answer? is there an issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. After some numerical experiments, it seems that $\Re{\left(ab\right)}$ can be any real numbers if $\Im{\left(ab\right)}\neq0$, yet this must be another open problem. Anyway, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Let
$$ f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+1 $$
have three distinct roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Since $f(x)$ is a real polynomial, it has at least a real root $x_1$. Since $0,x_1,x_2,x_3$ are concyclic, $x_2,x_3$ must be a pair of purely imaginary roots and hence the circle has the center $\frac12x_1$ with radius $\frac12|x_1|$. Let $x_{2,3}=r\pm si$ ($r,s\in\mathbb{R},s>0$). By Vieta's Theorem
$$ x_1+x_2+x_3=-a,x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3=b,x_1x_2x_3=-1$$
which give
$$ x_1+2r=-a,2rx_1+r^2+s^2=b,,x_1(r^2+s^2)=-1. \tag{1}$$
Also $|x_2-\frac12x_1|=|\frac12x_1|$ gives
$$ r^2+s^2=rx_1.\tag{2}$$
From (1) and (2), one has
$$ x_1=-\frac{1}{\sqrt {-r}}, a=\frac1{\sqrt{-r}}-2r,b=3\sqrt{-r},s=\sqrt{\sqrt{-r}-r^2}. $$
From this we can see $x_1<0,r<0$. Since $s>0$, one must have $r\in(-1,0)$. So
$$ ab=3+6(-r)^{3/2}.$$
Thus $$ 3<ab<9. $$

Comment: The question does not include that $f$ is a real polynomial, does it? This changes the problem completely.

Comment: There is an error at the end. One has $a b = 3 - 6 r \sqrt{-r}  = 3 + 6 (-r)^{3/2}$, so $a b\in (3, 9)$ in the case of the real polynomial, which does not contradict the statement of the question.

Comment: My calculation is still $ab=3+6r\sqrt{-r}$ which is different from your $ab=3-6r\sqrt{-r}$.

Comment: $a b = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{-r}}- 2 r) 3\sqrt{-r} = 3 - 6 r \sqrt{-r}$ (from the line after «From (1) and (2), one has»)

Comment: Now I see. Thanks.